# Apereo CAS surrogate authentication with REST api

Tags: java, cas, apereo

I'm successfully using Apereo 6.0.7 to authenticate my users via web login and JWT. I've also implemented delegate authentication to impersonate a given regular user with an admin profile.
Now I'd like to do the same procedure via Apereo REST API. I've successfully configured these API to authenticate a user with username and password. For example (via curl):

```
 curl -k -X POST \
  https://local.host.it:8444/cas/v1/tickets/ \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d 'token=true&username=andrea&password=secretpswd'
```

However I'm not able yet to perform a surrogate login. Using the configured separator to provide username adn surrogate doesn't work. For example, with / as separator (encoded as %2F):

```
 curl -k -X POST \
  https://local.host.it:8444/cas/v1/tickets/ \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d 'token=true&username=andrea%2Fsurrogate&password=secretpswd'
```

returns 401. Can anybody help me finding what's missing?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer. Surrogate support for API REST has been introduced in version 6.2.0

https://github.com/apereo/cas/commit/678d78dba004289a93466cbec9d28bcae7d57a14